# A confusion in understanding the sum of positive numbers proof

Tags: number-theory

I came across Ramanujan's proof in which he show that sum of positive integers is equal to negative one-twelfth.

$C=1+2+3+4......+\infty $

Subtracting $4C$ in such a way that every even term of $C$ gets subtracted from corresponding term of $4C$

$-3C=1-2+3-4......+\infty $

$-3C=1/4$

$C=-1/12$

The problem I am having understanding is the assumption that the terms $4C$ will only be subtracted by the even terms of $C$. How is that possible? Both infinities has the same number density and so it is not easily visualizable why $4C$ terms are only touching the even $C$ 
terms and not doing anything to the remaining terms.

Edit

I am fully aware how even terms are only touched of $C$ but what I am asking is why is the equal number density not a problem here. 
For example to generate an alternating sign integer series we do
$ \sum^N_{x=1} x -4\sum^{N/2}_{x=1} x$
The first sum goes till $N$ whereas the second will go till $N/2$.

If we apply this idea over the above case then $4C$ should have half the number density of $C$ but it doesn't, so isn't in this sense the above proof wrong?

Comment: The "equation" is , of course not true. This was discussed often here in the forum, again and again it was pointed out that it would be right "in some sense", but which sense ? The result is false (in the usual sense), no matter how it is actually meant. And it is bad that the formulation is apparantly so misleading that many, many people actually think it could be true in the usual sense. If there is "some sense", the source should point this out to avoid such terrible misunderstandings.

Comment: $1+1=0$ is correct if we are in $\mathbb Z_2$. But If I write this down and nothing else, it would surely be interpreted as a sum in the reals and then it is of course wrong.

Comment: Is this proof supposed to be serious?  It seems like a joke to get an desired result (the extended rieman zeta function for s=-1 is -1/12) and using the known fact the order manipultations of individual terms of a divergent series is inconsistant can be manipultated to get a false proof.

Comment: It's a sleight-of-hand, and it's problematic. While inserting arbitrary runs of zeros works for convergent series, summation methods for divergent series are often unstable (inserting zeros may change the sum or even produce a sequence for which the summation method isn't applicable).

Comment: @DanielFischer So, the reason for this equation is that it is tried to extend the infinite sum of the zeta-function to values for which it does not converge anymore ?

Comment: @Peter Using analytic continuation of the $\zeta$ series is a different argument, no $1-2+3-4+\dotsc$ occurs in that argument. There are various summation methods that produce the value $-\frac{1}{12}$ for the divergent series $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} n$, but the manipulation used here has a good chance to be invalid since the used summation method isn't stable, and then $4 + 8 + 12 + \dotsc \neq 0 + 4 + 0 + 8 + \dotsc$ in general. I don't know how Ramanujan argued in the place this is taken from, so it might or might not be valid.

Comment: You *can't* do it.  It is pure bull#### and I'm pretty sure Ramanujan knew.  What I don't understand is why it is claimed $\sum (-1)^{i+1} i = 1/4$??????  Probably by more bull####.

Comment: By extended zeta function, if it were the case that $|-1| < 1$ (which is not true) then it would be that $\zeta(-1) = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4+.....$ (but $|-1| \not < 1$ so it isn't true.)  And we know that $\zeta(-1)=  -1/12$.  So if it were true that $|-1| < 1$ it would be true that $1+2+3+4 +....= -1/12$.  Now $1+2+3+4+5+...$ diverges, and for divergent sums we can rearrange and "infinitely borrow" to make *any* other sum convergent or otherwise.  So we can rearrange $1+2+3+= a_1+ a_n+ a_3...= k$ for any $k$ we want.  So this is jut a clever way to get it so that we get a result we want.

Comment: @fleablood For $\lvert z\rvert < 1$, one has $$\frac{1}{(1+z)^2} = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1}n z^{n-1}.$$ As far as summation methods for divergent series are concerned, it's not a big step to plug $z = 1$ into that.

Comment: @DanielFischer Recently, in a post I mentioned that $\infty$ is no number , and someone responded that $\infty$ would be a number. Is this true ? Isn't $\infty$ rather a cardinality , sometimes called as " a number bigger than every natural number" ? What is your opinion ?

Comment: @fleablood Recently, in a post I mentioned that $\infty$ is no number , and someone responded that $\infty$ would be a number. Is this true ? Isn't $\infty$ rather a cardinality , sometimes called as " a number bigger than every natural number" ? What is your opinion ?

Comment: Meh.... If we're going to be hung as a thief we might as well just state $-1/12= \zeta(-1) = 1+2+3+4+5+6+... $ is a single line "proof".  I suppose if he is somehow showing a direct link between the zeta of funcition and $1/(1-1)^2 = 1-2+3-4+5-.....$ that'd be one thing.  But two clever lies to equal another clever lie is just.... being clever.

Comment: @Peter What's the definition of a number? Whether or not $\infty$ is a number depends on the definitions of "number" and of "$\infty$" in use. Using $\infty$ as a cardinality is typically not done, since there are many different infinite cardinalities. Sometimes it's a useful shorthand if one only cares about whether the cardinality is infinite and doesn't care which infinite cardinality it is.

Comment: @DanielFischer The question was about "very large numbers", like Graham's number and somewhere it went on with "any number besides $\infty$" . In this context, I would $\infty$ not call a "number".

Comment: No.... it's not.  You can create and "extended" real system so that $\infty$ and $-\infty$ are tossed into the mixed for different type of statements but one needs to recognize that is a *different* system (for different purposes) than the "number" system.  In this case $f(\infty)$ or $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}$ it just means $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}f(x)$ or $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\n}$ .

Comment: @fleablood Exactly my opinion.

Comment: Oh, I remember that post.  Um... the guy who posted it had a relatively inexperienced and naive idea about infitnity as a number.  Which is okay.  I'd let it go although it isn't really correct.

Comment: @fleablood I didn't respond ... In fact, considering $\infty$ as a number is harmless compared to the ultrafinitism.

Comment: Well, to be fair, one can say that only the natural numbers are "numbers" as they are "achievable units and only units can be numbers.  Which is fair in some context and not in others.  One can say $\infty + 1 = \infty$ and have it have a sensible mean *in context* and say that "in the extended real numbers $\infty$ is a number" and be correct in that context but in general... no, one should avoid saying such things.

Answer (score 0):

Subtracting $2C$ from $C$ deletes the even terms, so subtracting $4C$ instead reinstates the even terms with $-$ signs.

Comment: But why should subtracting $4C$ produce $1 - 2 + 3 - 4 +\dotsc$ rather than the obvious $-3 - 6 - 9 - \dotsc$?

Comment: Please see the edit

Comment: @DanielFischer That would also equal $-3C$, but would teach us nothing.